# How to the operator NOT with is.numeric

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to select all variables that are not numeric using `select_if` of tidyverse.

I tried:

```
mydata.dataframe %>%
  select_if(!is.numeric)
```

But I have an error message.
What is the correct way to do it please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is.numeric` is a *function*. `!`, by contrast, negates a *logical value*. Applying `!` to a function makes no sense. You need to *call* the function and negate its result.

In general you’d do the following:

```
select_if(function (x) ! is.numeric(x))
```

Or, using the lambda notation of tidyeval:

```
select_if(~ ! is.numeric(.x))
```

But R has a function factory to negate the result of a function:

```
select_if(Negate(is.numeric))
```

Answer (score 1):

another shorthand way to use function (x)

```
mydata.dataframe %>%
  select(where( ~ !is.numeric(.x)))
```